# Product Variants: Multiple Activities

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, variants

I'm using Product Variants in gradle/android studio to achieve the following project setup:

1. Two apps, that are 80% similar in one android studio project.
2. Each app should have its own manifest package path (they should basically behave like two independent apps - with it's own google api and push keys)

I've followed multiple tutorials in my attempt to achieve this (placeholders, multiple manifests) but nothing works.

Following this tutorial I did the following:
http://www.kevinrschultz.com/blog/2014/03/23/using-android-content-providers-with-multiple-package-names/

My build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '20'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    app1 {
        packageName "com.test.app1"
        //applicationId "com.test.app1"
    }

    app2 {
        packageName "com.test.app2"
        //applicationId "com.test.app2"
    }
}}
```

And here my manifest files.

src/main/manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application>
</application>
```

src/app1/manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name="com.test.app1”
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.test.app1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

src/app2/manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name="com.test.app2”
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.test.app2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
Manifest merger failed : Main AndroidManifest.xml at AndroidManifest.xml manifest:package attribute is not declared
```

Unfortunately I can't set a package to each individual manifest tag as my app requires different package paths. If I do it anyway, the merger is not able to merge the manifest files because of different package values. Besides packageName I also tried setting "applicationId" but this doesn't work, either. Using a placeholder like this `package="${applicationId}"` doesn't work because it doesn't resolve the variable value.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I'm using Android Studio 0.8.2 with gradle 0.12.2

Answer (score 4):

You can safely add

```
<manifest xmlns:android="..."
  package="com.test.app">
</manifest>
```

in your main manifest.

But you have to use `applicationId` and not `packageName` in your build.gradle.
The `applicationId` of the build.gradle will overwrite this value during your different builds.

A better way of doing this would be to use `applicationIdSuffix` instead of `applicationId` for your different product flavors.

The field have to be present in your main manifest.

Comment: This is what I get if I add package="com.test.app" and switch to applicationId.

/src/app1/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
 Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:2:70 value=(com.test.app1)
 has a different value=(com.flatiron) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:2:70 
 Suggestion : remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml  and place it in the build.gradle:
  flavorName {
   applicationId = "com.test.app1"
  }

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: What if you remove the `package=""` in your main Manifest but you keep the applicationId instead of packageName in your build.gradle. What is the exact error ?

Comment: src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
 Main AndroidManifest.xml at AndroidManifest.xml manifest:package attribute is not declared

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processApp1DebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Main AndroidManifest.xml at AndroidManifest.xml manifest:package attribute is not declared

Comment: I tried the following:
only in src/main/manifest set to package="" (the other untouched).
-> gives me the Overlay manifest error.

all manifests set to package="" gives me the following error:
/Users/ds/AndroidstudioProjects/TestApp/app/build/generated/source/r/app1/debug/Manifest.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
package ;
       ^

Gradle doesn't seem to replace anything in the manifest file?

Comment: Can you try to use the old manifest merger ? In your build.gradle, add  `useOldManifestMerger true` in the android plugin bloc. I remember reading that the new one is still buggy.

Comment: This is what I get if I activate the old merger and set the main package to "com.test.app", app1 to "com.test.app1" and app2 to "com.test.app2": FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergePassengerDebugManifests'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.

Unfortunately I don't see any further information in the Gradle Console, neither the ADB Logs/Logcat other than "15:37:08 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 2 sec"

Comment: try to remove it on app1 and app2, just leave the default one.

Comment: I think that pdegand59 is talking about this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables

Answer (score 3):

In addition to your `src/app1/AndroidManifest.xml` and `src/app2/AndroidManifest.xml` you will have a `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` which can contain elements both apps share.

In your flavor-specific manifests, you do not have to specify a `package` attribute, since that is already defined in your `build.gradle`.

In your main manifest however, you need to define a `package` attribute, to specify the package name used for your shared resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.test.app">
</manifest>
```

Make sure that you do not have any dependent libraries, which is also using that name, or you will get another build error.

Furthermore, you will want to specify `applicationId` instead of `packageName` in you `build.gradle` to decouple the package name used for identification of your app from the package name used for internal resource access.

Check this link for further information: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Answer (score 0):

I resolved same issue putting the same `package="com.ex.app"` in every flavor's manifest and putting `applicationId` and `useOldManifestMerger true` into `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    useOldManifestMerger true

    productFlavors{
        app1{
            applicationId = "com.ex.app1"
        }
        app2{
            applicationId = "com.ex.app2"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started over fresh but this time Android Studio generated the Variant configuration for me (under project settings there's a tab for flavors, variants, etc.)

I also decided to change the package name of all three variants to the same name as the identification of each app (variant) is done by the applicationId (which has nothing to do with the actual package names of the variants).

Thanks to pdegand59 for his help!